# xarray DataArray - how to fillna using ffill?

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

What would be the equivalent, if there is one, of the 
`Panel.ffill(axis=None, inplace=False, limit=None, downcast=None)` or `Panel.fillna(value=None, method=None, ...)` for a DataArray with three dimensions?

DataArray has a fillna method, but only takes a value as a parameter. `DataArray.fillna(value)`.

Example: how to fill the nan value using the previous non nan value with existing methods of xarray?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

data = np.random.rand(10, 3,3)
data[2,0,1]=np.NaN 

times = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=10)
dim1 = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
dim2 = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']

xrda = xr.DataArray(data, coords=[times, dim1, dim2], dims=['time', 'dim1', 'dim2'])
```

Comment: Currently no `ffill` in xarray, but contributions welcome. You may be able to do the same operation with numpy. Worst case you can pull into a MultiIndex-ed dataframe with the fill dimension only on the columns...